# Android using wrong layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I need to create diffrent layouts for diffrent phones.

I chekced 3 phones and screen sizes:

```
SONY XPERIA Z:
08-30 09:04:05.258 1008-1008/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: widthPixels  = 1080
08-30 09:04:05.258 1008-1008/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: heightPixels = 1776
08-30 09:04:05.258 1008-1008/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: densityDpi   = 480
08-30 09:04:05.258 1008-1008/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: xdpi         = 442.451
08-30 09:04:05.258 1008-1008/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: ydpi         = 443.345

Samsung s3:
08-30 09:05:00.179 21820-21820/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: widthPixels  = 480
08-30 09:05:00.179 21820-21820/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: heightPixels = 800
08-30 09:05:00.179 21820-21820/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: densityDpi   = 240
08-30 09:05:00.179 21820-21820/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: xdpi         = 234.0
08-30 09:05:00.179 21820-21820/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: ydpi         = 236.0

Sony xperia M
08-30 09:08:25.964 5391-5391/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: widthPixels  = 720
08-30 09:08:25.964 5391-5391/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: heightPixels = 1184
08-30 09:08:25.964 5391-5391/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: densityDpi   = 320
08-30 09:08:25.964 5391-5391/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: xdpi         = 345.056
08-30 09:08:25.964 5391-5391/pl.graphicbox.polamp I/LAYOUT: ydpi         = 342.231
```

and I created 3 layouts:

```
layout-sw200dp
layout-sw300dp
layout-sw400dp
```

but all phones using the same layout layout-sw300dp.

[image]

**Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong and how to repair this.** 
**Thx.**

Comment: check my edit, I did this.

Comment: check my edit, I forgot to add a line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like all phones have a width between 300 and 400 dp, and it is correct, when they use sw300dp.
To check it, add the `dpWidth` to the log:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
```

Comment: Yes, you have right. All devices are bettwen 320 and 360.. But Sony M and Sony Z has 360 width dp.. but screen sizes are diffrents.. what now?

Comment: @Esperanz0, unfortunately this is how Android works. dp is not an accurate unit. The goal is to make app's layout universal for the closest screen sizes, so it looks Ok on 5.2" as well as on 4.7" device. If you have problems with this, you should create a new question, and describe why you want 3 different layouts for such a similar devices.

Comment: I want create different layout because on Sony M layouts looks fine.. but on Sony Z texts are in multi line instead of single etc... thats why I wanted create own layout for...

Comment: @Esperanz0, you should post your layout, and screenshots from devices in new question. I'm sure, there is another, `correct` way to solve your problem