# Android different layouts for 4.0, 4.5 and 5.0 devices

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I need different layout for device 4.0 , 4.5 and 5.0.

But I checked screen size width using:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
```

And on

```
Sony Xperia Sp I have W: 360.0 H:  592.0
Sony Xperia Z I have the same result W: 360.0 H:  592.0
```

but screens have differents sizes and layout looks really diffrent.

**How to create different layouts for this and other devices sizes correctly?**

EDIT:

**In this case layouts look really different because one of phones had changed FONT SIZE in Device Settings.. GG Well played testers : )**

Thx all. Up vote.

Comment: Read the training tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html - sidenote, there is no such thing as Android 4.5

Comment: @mhenryk I guess OP refers to screen diagonal 4.5 inch

Answer (score 1):

Android uses density independent pixels (dp), so it should be quite easy to adapt to different sizes. In your res folder create subfolders like layout-w320p and customise your layout inside that folder to adapt to different screen sizes.

Always try using RelativeLayout instead of FrameLayout and position items relative to the device. Item sizes should be made wrap_content so that it will automatically be shrinked to the device.

Comment: I know it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221526/android-using-wrong-layout/39221695?noredirect=1#comment65781728_39221695.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide different layout based on exact width in pixels since you already know them:

**Examples**

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)

res/layout/main_activity.xml         # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-w600dp/main_activity.xml  # Multi-pane (any screen with 600dp available width or more)
```

Read the official android documentation about [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I know. But I Said 2 different devices(and sizes) has the same width in dp. So using the same layout in my example sw320dp. But I wanted different for Sony SP and Z.

Comment: Ah okay, do they have e different versions of android? Then you could add an Extra qualifier for platform version

Answer (score 1):

Sony Xperia Sp I have W: 360.0 H:  592.0Sony Xperia Sp I have W: 360.0 H:  592.0

> Sony Xperia Z I have the same result W: 360.0 H:  592.0.
>
> ## This is not screen size.. It totally depends on your device screen resolution.

If maintain this screen resolution you should create different layout or value file as

> value-sw320dp-hdpi
>   value-sw320dp-xhdpi
>   value-sw320dp-xxhdpi

## OR

> drawable-sw320dp-hdpi
>   drawable-sw320dp-xhdpi
>
> drawable-sw320dp-xxhdpi

Comment: value-sw320dp-hdpi value-sw320dp-xhdpi value-sw320dp-xxhdpi it helped